# PHP-Curl can't running in Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Error 500

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, php-curl

I'm trying to do a curl to send a message Whatsapp using PHP in my ubuntu server, i already installed **php5-curl** (see image bellow) but still get Error : 500 on browser. But if i run on xampp on windows its running well.
Is the any missconfiguration in my ubuntu server? thank you for kindly help.

this is php code :

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$token = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$data = [
    'phone' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'message' => 'hellow world',
];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        "Authorization: $token",
    )
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://domain/api/send-message");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

?>
```

**PHP Info**

[image]

Comment: add the following code to the beginning of the script and test again on server `if (!function_exists('curl_init')) { error_log('curl missing'); exit(); }`

Comment: thanks for reply, i already add your suggestion in the beginning of code and still error (HTTP ERROR 500).

Comment: which line does the code crash on? try running the code from the command line on the server

Comment: **PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/contoh_curl.php on line 4**. name of file above is contoh_curl.php

Comment: you got it, looks like curl is loaded twice. fix your php config on the server and you should be all set.

Comment: also switching from php5-* to php7-* would be a good idea

Comment: thanks for helping i just realized the my ubuntu server running on php 5.3.x that not support for using $data=[ ], i change with $data = array ( ) its running now. @8octopus

Comment: you're welcome @Fajar